# What does rake db:test:prepare actually do?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am following the rails tutorial videos and I can't figure out what the `db:test:prepare` command actually does. Can someone provide an explanation?

Answer (score 125, accepted):

> The rake db:migrate above runs any pending migrations on the
>   development environment and updates db/schema.rb. The rake
>   db:test:load recreates the test database from the current
>   db/schema.rb. On subsequent attempts, it is a good idea to first run
>   db:test:prepare, as it first checks for pending migrations and warns
>   you appropriately.

-- http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html

Basically it handles cloning the database so you don't have to run the migrations against test to update the test database.

Comment: `rake db:test:prepare` is now deprecated.

Comment: above url is dead, this would be the new one https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/4-1-stable/activerecord/CHANGELOG.md#rails-410-april-8-2014

Comment: and it is back  https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/5c4495538bb4e8808ce077f08ea6b809952daa44

Comment: @Jngai1297 No longer!

Comment: @Phillipp one more time http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v5.0/testing.html#maintaining-the-test-database-schema

Answer (score 43):

Specifically, `rake db:test:prepare` will do the following:

- Check for pending migrations and,
- load the test schema

That is, it will look your `db/schema.rb` file to determine if any migrations that exist in your project that have not been run. Assuming there are no outstanding migrations, it will then empty the database and reload it based on the contents of the `db/schema.rb` file.

Answer (score 4):

rake db:test:prepare is a good solution for PG issues like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21576686/pgundefinedtable-error-relation-does-not-exist-with-a-correct-rails-naming/28857695#28857695).

“PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR: relation does not exist” with a correct Rails naming and convention" where I couldn't just execute `rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=production`

When, for example you can't create test database for a bug discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19097558/pg-undefinedtable-error-relation-users-does-not-exist): "PG undefinedtable error relation users does not exist"

All arround this error 
"PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR: relation xxxxx does not exist”