# Setting up travis.ci with Rails and Postgres

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, travis-ci

I'm having trouble getting Rails, postgres travis to work. Keep getting a database connection error when the tests start running.

`Errno::ECONNREFUSED: Connection refused - connect(2)`

`.travis.yml`

```
language: ruby
rvm:
  - "1.9.3"
before_script:
  - cp config/database.travis.yml config/database.yml
  - psql -c 'create database myapp_test;' -U postgres
  - bundle exec rake db:migrate --trace
  - bundle exec rake db:test:prepare --trace
script:
  - RAILS_ENV=test bundle exec rake spec

gemfile: Gemfile.ci
```

and `database.travis.yml`

```
test:
  adapter: postgresql
  database: myapp_test
  username: postgres
```

I have to use separate database config.

Any clue what I'm doing wrong? Following the documentation almost exactly in http://about.travis-ci.org/docs/user/database-setup/ except I have to copy database config over to the right place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I needed to enable the elasticsearch service on travis. Adding records to the database requires indexing and the refused connection was to a nonexistent elasticsearch server.

Comment: Is there anywhere explained why you need an elasticsearch server?

Comment: @MarioUher my test suite had tests that was expecting a server avaiable

Comment: Ah ok. Wasn't mentioned anywhere and the the official docs included a link to an elastic search package as well. So I was very confused. But thankful the support from Travis is really good, and helped me with my problem.

Answer (score 2):

Why are you doing the

```
bundle exec rake db:migrate
bundle exec rake db:test:prepare
```

The db:test:prepare is going to try and access the development database, which doesn't exist.  And the rake db:migrate should be automatically run by Travis.

Comment: close, both the above commands will be run for the dev environment.

Comment: rake db:test:prepare does not access the development db I don't think. http://stackoverflow.com/a/15170024/986415

Comment: Yeah, without running migrations, travis doesn't do anything. https://travis-ci.org/collegedesis/collegedesis.com/builds/12551777

Comment: Travis runs in the test environment.  rake db:test:prepare will attempt to dump the dev database and load the schema into the test environment.  It shouldn't be necessary.  Travis should run migrations directly against the test db.

Comment: Just to be clear, run the bundle exec rake db:migrate, leave out the db:test:prepare

Comment: @PeterGoldstein, nope https://travis-ci.org/collegedesis/collegedesis.com/builds/12578085

Answer (score 0):

Based on the [doc](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/database-setup/#PostgreSQL), you should turn on the postgresql service first

```
services:
  - postgresql
```

And specify the DB type with (optional) :

```
    env:
      - DB=pgsql
```

NOTE: `postgresql` and `postgres` WILL NOT WORK. Please use `pgsql` !!!

Here is the full code that worked for me:

.travis.yml

```
language: ruby

rvm:
  - 2.2

env:
  - DB=pgsql

services:
  - postgresql

script:
  - RAILS_ENV=test bundle exec rake db:migrate --trace
  - bundle exec rake db:test:prepare
  - bundle exec rake

before_script:
  - cp config/database.yml.travis config/database.yml
  - psql -c 'create database courseselect_test;' -U postgres
```

config/database.yml.travis

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  pool: 5

development:
  <<: *default
  database: courseselect_development

test:
  <<: *default
  database: courseselect_test

production:
  <<: *default
  database: courseselect_developement
```

BTW, I also have the file `database.yml` with the same content as `config/database.yml.travis`