# Postgres views not recognized by rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, rspec, rails-activerecord

Using Rails 3.2.18 and Postgres, I have a few tables for which I have created a view to minimize the data loaded by ActiveRecord. Everything appears to be running correctly when in the application, but when I try to run Rspec I get:

```
 ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid:
       PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "properties_view" does not exist
```

(where 'properties_view' is the view on the 'properties' table)

What can I do to ensure that Rspec loads views properly from Postgres?

Comment: possibly related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21576686/pgundefinedtable-error-relation-does-not-exist-with-a-correct-rails-naming

Comment: Are you use a `schema.rb` or `structure.sql` file to keep track of your database structure?

Comment: @muistooshort yes! Thank you - that is a very insightful question. I do have a schema.rb file and it does not include the views! I will investigate further.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Rails doesn't really understand "advanced" database concepts like views so they won't appear in your `schema.rb`. When rspec is setting up its test database, it will use `schema.rb` to create the database schema, since you won't find your views in `schema.rb`, you won't find your views in the test database that rspec will be using and everything falls apart.

The solution is to switch from `schema.rb` to `structure.sql`. You should be able to update your `config/application.rb` to say:

```
config.active_record.schema_format = :sql
```

and then do a `rake db:structure:dump` to generate the `structure.sql` file. Once you have that, remove `schema.rb` from your file system and revision control, add `structure.sql`, and try again.

Comment: I can always count on learning something from SO. :) I assume this could have database-dependent stuff? Caveat emptor.

Comment: @zetetic: Yes, `structure.sql` will be database dependent but (a) so are views and (b) database portability is largely a myth unless you do it the hard way (i.e. by hand the hard way).

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to switch to the SQL schema format, using the scenic gem may help ([Scenic Gem Gitub](https://github.com/scenic-views/scenic)).

They allow you to add SQL Views (also materialized) to migrations and also adds them to your ruby schema.

Worked for me like a charm.