# Running db:test:prepare in Rake task throws off environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, rake

I have the following 2 `rake` tasks:

```
task :clone => :environment do |t, args|
  Rake::Task["db:drop"].invoke 
  Rake::Task["db:create"].invoke
  system "pg_restore -O -d database_name last_dump"
  Rake::Task["db:migrate"].invoke
  Rake::Task["db:test:prepare"].invoke

  # Try to force the rails env to reload, but this doesn't solve the problem
  Rake::Task["environment"].execute
  Rake::Task["db:company_count"].invoke
end

task :company_count => :environment do
  puts Company.count
end
```

When I run `rake db:clone` the output the `Company.count` is 0 indicating there are no Companies in the database, but when I run `rake db:clone && rake db:company_count` the output is 2.

How do I get the correct `Company.count` after loading the database in the first task?

The `Company.count` is correct if I remove `Rake::Task["db:test:prepare"].invoke` from the `clone` task, but I'm not sure why

Answer (score 1):

My guess is first task is not using the console environment because it creates its own terminal session for the rake, and the second one is.

Try `printenv` and compare the variables

Also try prefixing the commands with `RAILS_ENV=development` or whatever environment you want.

Answer (score 1):

[guides.rubyonrails.org](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#maintaining-the-test-database-schema) indicates that the task `db:test:prepare` is used to do the following to your test database:

1. drop the database
2. create the database
3. run the migrations

After this task completes, you will not have any data in there.  Here are stack overflow answers that explains this:

1. [PG undefinedtable error relation users does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19315373/5586783)
2. [What does rake db:test:prepare actually do](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15170024/5586783)

I believe the behavior you are seeing has nothing to do with the environment, but a misunderstanding in the intention of this rake task.

Comment: Does `db:test:prepare` manipulate the test environment DB? Why does it afftect the development environment?

Comment: I think running db:test:prepare sets the RAILS_ENV to test.  That is why the count is 0 after executing that command, you are working against test.